# If the James Webb Space Telescope explodes, is there a backup?

Tags: james-webb-telescope

With the launch of the [JWST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/James_Webb_Space_Telescope) nearing, what happens in the worst case? Let's say the rocket explodes and everything is 100% lost.

Are there back-up copies? Is everything on it one-of-a-kind? Is there a duplicate sister telescope and a time table for launch?

I did see that [NASA built an identical copy a "twin" of the Perseverance Rover.](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-0GMURCDBM)

Comment: No backup, the thing was already expensive enough.

Comment: @AtmosphericPrisonEscape I mean, I can't find anything about it, but there [was a twin of the Perseverance Rover](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w-0GMURCDBM).

Comment: I think there is no duplicate question here related to a replacement of this monster-large and generational space telescope effort. Here are some related  questions: [Do long term missions receive insurance coverage?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/1347/12102) and [Who pays when a mission to the ISS fails?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/9722/12102)

Comment: Your concern over a potential catastrophe is such a compelling one that it's been asked about few times before, but not in terms of a replacement: [What happens if Ariane V actually fails while launching JWST?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57283/12102) and [Will the James Webb Space Telescope be insured against launch failure?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/24717/12102)

Comment: @EvanCarroll cool! I've just asked [What would have to be done to Perseverance's twin rover Optimism to make it capable of a limited Mars roving mission?](https://space.stackexchange.com/q/57331/12102)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Will the James Webb Space Telescope be insured against launch failure?](https://space.stackexchange.com/questions/24717/will-the-james-webb-space-telescope-be-insured-against-launch-failure)

Comment: For sure there is a plan B, unfortunately (ask PM Johnson). If something like this happens https://youtu.be/PK_yguLapgA?t=48 one just have to pick up the pieces and carry on. That's plan B. And put them all together again as a good answer to an "interesting" question.

Comment: There's always more money to burn

Comment: "Sure, it's costing us $9 billion per telescope--but we make it up on _volume_."

Comment: [First rule in government spending: Why build one when you can have two at twice the price?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VTUrdizRZyw)

Comment: If you have something that costs about $10 billion, would you rather say "eh, let's build another one just in case it explodes" or "let's do everything we can to make sure it doesn't explode"?

Comment: I guess if it explodes, it would take less than 10 billion dollars (and 20 years) to build another one, as all the plans are still there (and the science needed to build the first one). Though they might opt to build something based on newer tech instead.

Comment: @PaŭloEbermann They'd probably fast-track the next one and take the loss of JWST as just that, a loss.

Answer (score 41):

I want to clarify something about that "twin" of the Perseverance rover that you've mentioned, something that won't easily fit in a comment.

NASA built a twin of the rover not to have one as a backup rover in case the original rover explodes in transit or fails to land. They built one because they need a way to plan out movements in advance. Mars is so far away that it is impossible to directly control any device on the planet through manual control. It takes radio signals between 6 and 20 minutes to get to Mars, and it takes the return signals just as long to get back. So at best you have a 12 minute gap and worst you have a 45 minute gap between you sending the signals and you knowing the outcome of the command. So you need to be REALLY damn sure that you're sending the right commands, because there is no roadside assistance that can help you if you accidentally hit a rock or get stuck in a sand dune.

To that end, NASA uses the rover's twin here on Earth to meticulously prepare every command they send by first testing it with the twin, without the delay, on a recreation of the Mars rover's immediate area, including the shape and texture of rocks and the layout of the mars dirt they're driving on. Every command, from driving forward to sampling a rock to moving the camera to take a close-up picture is first tested in that simulated environment before sending it to Mars, similar to how a competent software developer tests their newly written software on a separate testing environment BEFORE they push their new code to a production environment.

Comment: Fun fact:   There is not a complete copy of the JWST here on the ground.

Answer (score 25):

There is no backup telescope.

> There’s no room for error with the Webb, no backup telescope in a warehouse, and no chance of repairing it once it launches.

https://www.inverse.com/science/james-webb-new-delay

Comment: What is the possibility of "WFIRST or Nancy Grace Roman telescope" taking JWST's job? Is it possible to modify it and to use it as backup?

Comment: @SwiftPushkar Maybe, but building a completely new spacecraft with a different design is not what is meant by a "duplicate sister telescope".

Comment: There was no chance of repairing Hubble when it launched. Which was lucky, because I made a lot of money fixing the images, until someone, uh, repaired it. Damn.